# LDAP listening on localhost but hostname or IP

Tags: linux, sockets, connection, listener, openldap

I've installed LDAP on a raspberryPI running Raspian, which is a Debian fork I think.

I have a DB and entries and can do an LDAP search successfully from the server if I use -h localhost or -h 127.0.0.1. But if I use the hostname or IP I get an error message:

```
root@rpi1:~# ldapsearch -d 1 -x -h 10.10.0.11 -b "ou=Groups,dc=pi,dc=home"
ldap_create
ldap_url_parse_ext(ldap://10.10.0.11)
ldap_sasl_bind
ldap_send_initial_request
ldap_new_connection 1 1 0
ldap_int_open_connection
ldap_connect_to_host: TCP 10.10.0.11:389
ldap_new_socket: 4
ldap_prepare_socket: 4
ldap_connect_to_host: Trying 10.10.0.11:389
ldap_pvt_connect: fd: 4 tm: -1 async: 0
attempting to connect:
connect errno: 111
ldap_close_socket: 4
ldap_err2string
ldap_sasl_bind(SIMPLE): Can't contact LDAP server (-1)
```

The weird thing for me is that the service is running an listening on the port:

```
    root@rpi1:~# nmap 10.10.0.11

Starting Nmap 6.47 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2015-12-30 22:16 UTC
Nmap scan report for rpi1.pi.home (10.10.0.11)
Host is up (0.00017s latency).
Not shown: 997 closed ports
PORT    STATE SERVICE
22/tcp  open  ssh
80/tcp  open  http
636/tcp open  ldapssl

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 26.78 seconds
root@rpi1:~#
root@rpi1:~#
root@rpi1:~#
root@rpi1:~#
root@rpi1:~# nmap localhost

Starting Nmap 6.47 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2015-12-30 22:17 UTC
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.00018s latency).
Other addresses for localhost (not scanned): 127.0.0.1
Not shown: 996 closed ports
PORT    STATE SERVICE
22/tcp  open  ssh
80/tcp  open  http
389/tcp open  ldap
636/tcp open  ldapssl

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 26.82 seconds
```

You can see that scanning localhost shows that the service is listening on 389, but not if I use the server's IP or hostname.

So I have no way of getting a client on another server to connect, because it only seems to be listening on localhost..... This is beyond my limited understanding I'm afraid.

As far as I can see I am resolving the name ok:

```
root@rpi1:~# host rpi1
rpi1 has address 10.10.0.11

root@rpi1:~# host rpi1.pi.home
rpi1.pi.home has address 10.10.0.11

root@rpi1:~# host ldap.pi.home
ldap.pi.home has address 10.10.0.11
```

Proof that the DB is working:

```
root@rpi1:~# ldapsearch -x -h 127.0.0.1 -b "cn=Bradley Atkins,cn=musedev,ou=Groups,dc=pi,dc=home"
# extended LDIF
#
# LDAPv3
# base <cn=Bradley Atkins,cn=musedev,ou=Groups,dc=pi,dc=home> with scope subtree
# filter: (objectclass=*)
# requesting: ALL
#

# Bradley Atkins, musedev, Groups, pi.home
dn: cn=Bradley Atkins,cn=musedev,ou=Groups,dc=pi,dc=home
cn: Bradley Atkins
givenName: Bradley
gidNumber: 501
homeDirectory: /home/users/batkins
sn: Atkins
loginShell: /bin/sh
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: posixAccount
objectClass: top
uidNumber: 1001
uid: batkins

# search result
search: 2
result: 0 Success

# numResponses: 2
# numEntries: 1
```

Can anyone suggest a way forward?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

As the `nmap` output shows clearly, it's listening at 127.0.0.1, not 0.0.0.0.

Comment: Yes, it is listening, I posted the map output to show that it is. My question is, why doesn't it seem to be listening when I use the server's IP or hostname? I cannot connect a client to this machine using 127.0.0.1, I need to use its hostname or IP.

Comment: After several hours of investigation it finally dawned on me that you meant I should configure it to listen on 0.0.0.0 and weren't just pointing out that it was listening on 127.0.0.1. I found the setting in slapd.conf  and now it works from any server in the network. Thanks.

Comment: @BradleyAtkins Please share your findings

Comment: @BradleyAtkins It baffles me why it took you several hours to understand something that is already clearly stated in this answer.